# Is there a Python or R package to access the "tags" of Windows 10 files?

Tags: python, r, windows-10, metadata

I would like to organize images by different categories with tags on Windows10. [This is an example of the info I would like to read](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zMCQM.jpg).
I also need to preserve the file names, since they contain other useful information. I want to later have a list, or a dataframe, with the file name and the corresponding tag name.

Most google searches about accessing files metadata suggest reading the `exif` metadata of the image but this does not contain the "tag" info given on Windows10. Apparently the tags are stored on `NTFS` (https://karl-voit.at/2019/11/26/Tagging-Files-With-Windows-10/). Trying to access the tags with Python's [IPTCInfo3](https://pypi.org/project/IPTCInfo3/) doesn't work either.

Does anyone know how to read these tags from Python or R?